# trigger specific on() click once without user clicking it

Tags: jquery

I would like to fire .example once without the user clicking .example

```
$(document).on("click",".example",function() {
    // Do Stuff
}
```

FYI -This would happen when the document would load. How would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute it on the document ready

**HTML**

```
<a id="foo" class="example" href="#" >foo link </a>
```

**Script**

```
$(function(){   

    //bind the event
    $('.example').bind('click', function() {
      alert("clicked");
    });

    //now call it on document ready
    $('.example').trigger('click');    


});
```

Here is the working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/7d5ug/16/

Answer (score 0):

While you could simulate a click on the item, this is a little brittle. What happens if you change the DOM element that the user clicks on? Now you will have to update that element's selector in two different places.

A more robust solution is to break the event handler into a real function:

```
function myHandler() { ... }
```

And then to call the function wherever you need to:

```
// Call when event fires
$(document).on("click", ".example", myHandler);

// Call when documentReady
$(function() {
    myHandler();
});
```